# NGINX mail proxy: How to define an nginx.conf file to proxy smtp to a mail server runnning on a separate server?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to set up an nginx mail proxy server so I've defined a mail nginx.conf entry like this:

```
...........
    mail {
        server_name postal.mydomain.com;
        proxy_pass_error_message on;
        auth_http http://192.168.1.95:5001/auth;    
    
        server {
            listen     2525;
            protocol   smtp;
            #proxy_pass 192.168.1.95:2525;
            smtp_auth none;
        }
    }
...........
```

The problem is that the mail server (postal in my case) is not on the same host as the nginx. It is actually running on host 192.168.1.95.

If I try to define a proxy_pass entry under server, nginx won't start and it will complain that the proxy_pass is not supported at that location.

Searching the web, I was not able to locate a conf file example for a scenario like mine.

How exactly i can instruct nginx to proxy the email trafic to my backed mail server?

Thanks